# Delta index updates not automatic

Tags: mysql, sphinx

Unfortunately, I think the error is not so that he has automatically updated the delta

I have this table addet in "database"

```
# in MySQL
CREATE TABLE sph_counter
(
counter_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
max_doc_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);


source database
{
type            = mysql

sql_host        = localhost
sql_user        = root  
sql_pass        = root
sql_db          = database
sql_port        = 3306  # optional, default is 3306

sql_query       = \
    SELECT ID, name, dir, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ctime) AS ctime, \
    FROM database

sql_field_string = dir
sql_field_string = name

}

source delta : database
{
sql_range_step  = 2
sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
sql_query = SELECT id, title, body FROM documents \
    WHERE id>( SELECT max_doc_id FROM sph_counter WHERE counter_id=1 )
sql_query_pre = REPLACE INTO sph_counter_rls SELECT 1, MAX(ID) FROM `database`
}

index delta : database
{
source = database
path = /home/data/delta
}

index database 
{ 
source          = database 
path            = /home/data/database
docinfo         = extern 
#charset_type       = sbcs 
morphology          = none 
stopwords           = 
# minimum indexed word length 
# default is 1 (index everything) 
min_word_len        = 1 
charset_table       = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, a..z, -, U+0028, U+0029 
#enable_star        = 1 
min_prefix_len      = 0 
min_infix_len       = 2 
ngram_len       = 0 
}
```

edit: i have addet : index delta ...

indexer --all
Sphinx 2.2.11-id64-release (95ae9a6)
Copyright (c) 2001-2016, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2016, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'database'...
collected 100 docs, 0.0 MB
sorted 0.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 100 docs, 8982 bytes
total 0.078 sec, 114887 bytes/sec, 1279.08 docs/sec
indexing index 'delta'...
collected 100 docs, 0.0 MB
sorted 0.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 100 docs, 8982 bytes
total 0.063 sec, 140585 bytes/sec, 1565.19 docs/sec
total 212 reads, 0.000 sec, 0.3 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 24 writes, 0.000 sec, 6.3 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg

Comment: Hi. So what's the question? What are you 'indexer' commands and schedule? Do you have any crontasks for that?

Comment: I have with indexer --all the index created, and thought so far that with this config automatically updated. is a corntab necessary? when yes, how? I wand not complete new index make

Answer (score 0):

You 'delta' index can't be built at all since it doesn't defined in the config. Only 'delta' SOURCE is defined. And there's only INDEX - database which uses source 'database', not 'delta'

Comment: I have addet  index delta : database
{
source = database
path = /home/data/delta
}, must i indexer --merge databse delta --rotate run after each insert?

Comment: it depends on many things. In most cases you just update your bigger index let's say once per day and your delta index - once per minute, so you have 2 crontasks: 'indexer --all --rotate - for main+delta' and 'indexer delta --rotate'. But if it takes too long to rebuild the bigger index completely you can use 'indexer --merge'. I also suggest you to read about kill lists and real time indexes.

Comment: have I understood that correctly, pre minute i make "indexer --merge databse delta --rotate" and "indexer delta --rotate"? does it matter which one first? Regards

Comment: how would a realtime config look like?

Comment: You first need to do just 'indexer delta' (with --rotate if it's used by your running searchd or w/o --rotate otherwise) to update the delta index, then use 'indexer --merge ... --rotate'. The order matters as if you do 'indexer --merge' first it will merge your older 'delta' index.

Comment: To understand RealTime indexes I recommend this course https://play.manticoresearch.com/rtintro/